# Aurora Postgres memory - high Aurora Storage Daemon usage

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I assumed that when I purchased a db.r4.xlarge instance for Aurora Serverless Postgres RDS, that I was getting [30.5GB of RAM](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/instance-types/) which would be mostly available to Postgres.

[image]

However, I was puzzled when finding from all the monitoring charts that my available memory seems to be ~8GB.  For example

[image]

Finally, I stumbled on "OS process list" in the RDS console: Databases > Choose my DB > Monitoring > Choose OS process list from the Monitoring dropdown

[image]

... to find that this Aurora Storage Daemon is taking the majority of my memory!

Is this normal?  Am I reading this table correctly?  Did I configure something wrong?  I guess the daemon goes away when you get a regular RDS instance?  Can Aurora benefits be that good that it justifies taking SO much of my RAM?

Answer (score 1):

Aurora Storage Daemon is the process which connects postgres to the storage, so if your database has too much write operations, then this is the daemon which is responsible to write into the database.

Aurora Storage Daemon uses a lot of available memory If engine needs more memory due to workload increasing, then aurora storage daemon will reclaim its internal caches automatically and this behavior of the Aurora Storage Daemon is expected in such scenario.